# Using a list comprehension to label data that is common to two lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have two lists, A and B.  I want to generate a third list that is 1 if the corresponding entry in A has an entry in the list B at the end of the string and 0 otherwise.

```
A = ['Mary Sue', 'John Doe', 'Alice Stella', 'James May', 'Susie May']
B = ['Smith', 'Stirling', 'Doe']
```

I want a list comprehension that will give the result

```
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Keep in mind that this is a specific case of a more general problem.  Elements in A can have arbitrary white space and contain an arbitrary number of words in them.  Likewise elements in B can have an arbitrary number of words.  For example

```
A = ['  Tom Barry Stirling Adam', 'Maddox Smith', 'George Washington Howard Smith']
B = ['Washington Howard Smith', 'Stirling Adam']
```

should return

```
[1, 0, 1]
```

So far I have the following

```
[1 if y.endswith(x) else 0 for x in B for y in A]
```

However the length of the returned list is not the dimension that I want because it gives a 0 or 1 for every combination of A[i], B[j] elements.  I am not interested in solutions using for loops, I need a list comprehension for speed.

Comment: Will the first name always be skipped and always full substrings that are matched?

Comment: No, there can be cases where A and B can contain the exact same name.

Comment: So literally any variation is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A much faster way is to pass a tuple to *endswith*:

```
In [8]: A = ['Mary Sue', 'John Doe', 'Alice Stella', 'James May', 'Susie May']

In [9]: B = ['Smith', 'Stirling', 'Doe']            

In [10]: A *= 1000

In [11]: %%timeit                                                          
t = tuple(B)
[int(s.endswith(t)) for s in A]
   ....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 5.02 ms per loop

In [12]: timeit [int(any(full.endswith(last) for last in B)) for full in A]
100 loops, best of 3: 21.3 ms per loop
```

You make *one function call* per element in `A` as opposed to one function call for potentially every element in B for each in `A` and without the overhead of the generator used with *any*.

You can see using a larger set of words just how much faster it is especially if the matches are sparse:

```
In [2]: from random import sample

In [6]: A = [s.strip() for s in open("/usr/share/dict/american-english")][:20000]

In [7]: B = sample([s.strip() for s in open("/usr/share/dict/british-english")], 2000)

In [8]: %%timeit                                                                      
t = tuple(B)
[int(s.endswith(t)) for s in A]
   ...: 

1 loop, best of 3: 2.16 s per loop
In [9]: timeit [int(any(full.endswith(last) for last in B)) for full in A]              
1 loop, best of 3: 26.6 s per loop
```

You said you don't want loops but as the lists grow sorting might be a better option, then bisect to find any matched strings with a log n search reversing the logic:

```
from  bisect import bisect_left


def compress(l1, l2):
    srt1 = sorted(s[::-1] for s in l2)
    hi = len(l2)
    for ele in l1:
        rev = ele[::-1]
        ind = bisect_left(srt1, rev, hi=hi)
print(list(compress(A, B)))
```

The runtime is O(N log N) as opposed to the quadratic approach checking every substring.

Comment: Wow, much faster!  Even factoring in the tuple conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Your condition needs to hold the `B` list. Your proposed solution will generate a `0` or `1` for every pair of (A, B) elements.

```
[1 if any(full.endswith(last) for last in B) else 0 for full in A]
```

But you can also take advantage of `bool` to `int` conversion

```
[int(any(full.endswith(last) for last in B)) for full in A]
```

You can save some time by using a `set` and the `in` operator as well:

```
B = {'Smith', 'Stirling', 'Doe'} # set for a more efficient `in`
[int(full.split()[-1] in B) for full in A]
```

Comment: Your first two solutions work great.  The third uses split and as I explained in a comments on other solutions won't work for me because it won't handle cases where the A list might have something like 'Mary Pat Sue' that should be labeled as 1 if the B list contains 'Pat Sue' or 'Sue'.

Comment: @deltap you should update your question to reflect this instead of adding comments or you'll continue to get similar answers.

Comment: I've been doing some timing benchmarks and it seems that using `int()` may be slightly slower than using the `if` ... `else` (in pypy).

Comment: @deltap maybe, but idk why you wouldn't just want `True` and `False` to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> [[0, 1][name.split()[-1] in set(B)] for name in A]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

edit: For finer control over the check.

[**`str.split`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) can take a parameter which is the maximum splits to make. e.g:

```
>>> 'Mary Pat Sue'.split(maxsplit=1)
['Mary', 'Pat Sue']
```

Then we could compare to see if any name in `B` is in the second value of split:

```
>>> B = ['Pat', 'Sue']
>>> any(name in 'Pat Sue' for name in B)
True
```

So altogether:

```
>>> [[0, 1][any(surname in fullname.split(maxsplit=1)[-1] for surname in B)]
     for fullname in A]
```

Comment: This is a slight abstraction of a slightly more complicated problem.  I can't use split like that because the A list might have something like 'Mary Pat Sue' that should be labeled as 1 if the B list contains 'Pat Sue' or 'Sue'.

Answer (score 0):

`[1 if a.split(' ')[1] in B else 0 for a in A]`

Comment: This is a slight abstraction of a slightly more complicated problem. I can't use split like that because the A list might have something like 'Mary Pat Sue' that should be labeled as 1 if the B list contains 'Pat Sue' or 'Sue'.

Comment: [**`str.split`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) splits on whitespace by default.

Answer (score 0):

How big is B in real life? You could turn it into a regular expression.

```
A = ['Mary Sue', 'John Doe', 'Alice Stella', 'James May', 'Susie May']
B = ['Smith', 'Stirling', 'Doe']
```

turn B into `".*(?:Smith|Stirling|Doe)$"` then compile to regex

```
import re
end_with_b = re.compile(".*(?:{})$".format("|".join(B))

a_matches = [1 if ends_with_b.match(a) else 0 for a in A]
```

Or, create your own filter function

```
def my_filter(a):
    return 1 if any(a.endswith(b) for b in B) else 0

a_matches = [my_filter(a) for a in A]
```

Comment: B can be quite large.  At the moment it is ~200,000 entries but in principle it could be more.  A is also large, having millions of entries.